# Editing stl files for unwanted multiple parts

Tags: 3d-models

I have a Creality CR-10S5 and am printing a large ocean liner model in sections. The problem I am coming up against is that when the person built the model, the 100's of portholes extend into the interior of the model. I've had issues where the long end of the porthole on the interior of the model as it is printing starts to bend upward and has interrupted the path of the extruder and it starts printing about an inch to left on the X-axis.

I was wondering if anyone knew of an easier way than bringing it into Meshmixer or Fusion and individually cutting these long porthole extensions I will call them away from the inside of the model. I've tried using the hollow out feature but they still remain. I've thought about cutting them along a plane in Fusion but that would slice the entire model.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing SE and thank you for your contribution. If you could [edit] in a screenshot of the model that could help in finding a solution. Also, when you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other components to the vessel intruding into the volume of the model, consider to create a suitably primitive shape centered in the hull. By creating a boolean union, the new primitive will "absorb" the empty space and terminate the noodles. The result will be a hollow model, more or less as the original, but with a thicker wall.

Comment: Thanks, that is a great idea that I’m going to try out. I can probably cut part of the same model and decrease it’s size to use it to cut out the noodles as you say. Thanks so much!